# Looking for a short poem which is a parodic pastiche of Shakespeare plots (possibly published in the New Yorker)

Tags: poetry, identification-request

A few years ago, in a poetry podcast, the guest read out a poem which was a parodic pastiche of Shakespeare plots. It wasn't based on any specific Shakespeare plot, but it was meant to seem like a Shakespearean comedy's plot. (I don't think it was trying to sound like Shakespeare's poetry; it was just trying to sound like a lively plot synopsis of Shakespeare.)

I am almost certain I heard this on the New Yorker Poetry Podcast, so it would have been published in the New Yorker at some point. (And I am almost certain the poet was not the one reading the poem on the podcast, so the poem could be decades old.)

I can't remember the exact details, but some of the main jokes were: introducing a lot of characters whose name begin with "P" (or some other alliteration); piling plot development on plot development very quickly; ending the poem with something like "and now act 2".

Comment: I looked through the _Complete New Yorker_ DVD collection (up to 2008) and couldn't find anything. Given the scant details you mention makes it difficult though.